# Find a data throughout out other data mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I've literally no idea how to find the "via" field from 'sede' table starting from the "cognome" field in 'impiegato' table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`impiegato` (
  `codice` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` VARCHAR(45),
  `nomedipart` VARCHAR(45),
  `sede` VARCHAR(45),
  `data` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`codice`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`sede`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`sede` (
  `cittaSede` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `via` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cap` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cittaSede`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`dipartimento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`dipartimento` (
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cittaSede` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(45),
  `codDirett` VARCHAR(45),
  INDEX `fk_dipartimento_idx` (`codDirett` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`nome`),
  INDEX `fk_sede_idx` (`cittaSede` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dipartimento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codDirett`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`impiegato` (`codice`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sede`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cittaSede`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`sede` (`cittaSede`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`progetto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`progetto` (
  `nomeProgetto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `budget` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`nomeProgetto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`partecipazione`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`partecipazione` (
  `codImpieg` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `progetto` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`codImpieg`),
  INDEX `fk_progetto_idx` (`progetto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_impiegato`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codImpieg`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`impiegato` (`codice`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_progetto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`progetto`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`progetto` (`nomeProgetto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What is the "via" data in the "cognome" data?

Comment: I was asking to find the "via" from 'sede' table starting to "cognome" in 'impiegato' table

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you know how to do an INNER JOIN? You just need to do some joins on the tables, using your foreign keys. `impiegato.codice` links to `dipartimento.codDirett`. `dipartimento.cittaSede` links to `sede.cittaSede`. Using those fields to join the tables together, you can get the related records. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx will show you the basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the `impiegato` row with the desired `cognome` with the row in `sede` with the same `sede` value, and that's what `joins` do:

```
select  via
from    sede s
join    impiegato i
on      s.sede = i.sede
where   i.cognome = 'desiredCognome'
```